# cant download files uploaded tree.io

Tags: python, django, apache, treeio-django

All the files I upload to the tree.io tickets, projects, etc cannot be downloaded,

I am getting a 404 error.

I am running tree.io in a cantos 6 box.

any ideas to get this working please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after sometime found a solution for this.

1. i had to define the MEDIA_ROOT as an absolute URL in the settings.py
2. when i went to static/media there was no folder called attachments, i had to make one and give it the correct permissions for python can write to that folder.

this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks nivanka, I've updated the git repository with the attachments folder using a .gitignore file in that dir. An empty directory doesn't get stored by git.